Azure DevOps - Release Pipeline - Download pipeline artifact task - Dedup size does not match the downloaded size Error
I have a build pipeline for my Angular project in Azure DevOps and have publish pipeline artifact task as shown in below image:
It runs and successfully published the things on the path.
When I run the Release pipeline to deploy the build on my on prem server. Download pipeline artifact gives me below error:

One or more errors occurred. (Dedup size does not match the downloaded size. DedupId: CC31F993CCBEC8475BA0FDCF57D9CDC12E7CC726128357B722F1090C3AC0574D01) (Dedup size does not match the downloaded size. DedupId: 4638EA88509550F8422E21A188FC68A0700B006936378A93017FE2E30F70E36401)

I tried Published Build Artifact task as well in my build pipeline that build the things but in release pipeline it also don't download the published artifacts and was also throwing "Error: unable to verify the first certificate".
Need help what is this error and what will be the resolution of it?
Thanks in Advance.

Coincidence or not, there were some issues on Azure DevOps today: https://status.dev.azure.com/_history
Hopefully this is just a temporary issue.

@RuiJarimba Thanks for the reply. Yes i had already seen this page but issue is coming since last 2 days when i was moved to Publish Pipeline Artifact task instead using Publish Build Artifact task. Because Publish Build Artifact task was also throwing "Error: unable to verify the first certificate" error suddenly. Three days before everything was working fine since 4 years.

Everything works, until it stops working :-) Outages and other temporary issues might happen once in a while.

Hope so it will be a temporary issue and will be fixed automatically. :S

Hi , it seems you are using the self-hosted agent. Could you try to use the Microsoft hosted agent and check if the same issue happens? This can help narrow down the issue.

Hello, I tried both agents but issue is same for both. @MiaoTian-MSFT

Hi, thanks for your response. Could you please build a new artifact in your pipeline and download the latest one in your release pipeline? Just to check if the old artifact is broken. You can also create a new pipeline (not the release pipeline) and manually add the Download pipeline artifact to the pipeline to check if it works.

At the same time, this error "Error: unable to verify the first certificate" seems the same with the one in this ticket. If you are a ESET user, the error may relate to this issue.

@MiaoTian-MSFT Yes you are right. This was ESET issue. We have updated ESET and that certificate issue is now gone and everything is now working back. Thank you so much for your reply. Really Appreciated.

Hi, glad to hear that everything is now working. I've summarized the reason for the problem in the answer. Happy coding!

This error "Error: unable to verify the first certificate" is the same with the one in this ticket, which shows that it could be caused by the ESET Antivirus which blocks the node call.
You confirmed that you are a ESET user and the error is related to this issue. You have updated ESET and that certificate issue is now gone. Everything is now working back.
